# news on mobile sharepoint app won't show up

Tags: mobile, sharepoint, feed

0

i'm working with a sharepoint online site and in this site there are some news, the newer one was posted on april 2023, and if I create a new news it will appear on the news tab of the mobile app, but the news that already exists won't show up. If I open from the browser one of the news from april and save it for later, I can see the news oin the app under news-> saved for later.

I'd like to know how the news tab work and how it manage the news, in which way it choose to show up a news or no? if they get older than a month they will disappear? which are the criteria for the news to show or no to show them?

thanks in advance Giulio

0

i'm working with a sharepoint online site and in this site there are some news, the newer one was posted on april 2023, and if I create a new news it will appear on the news tab of the mobile app, but the news that already exists won't show up. If I open from the browser one of the news from april and save it for later, I can see the news oin the app under news-> saved for later.

I'd like to know how the news tab work and how it manage the news, in which way it choose to show up a news or no? if they get older than a month they will disappear? which are the criteria for the news to show or no to show them?

Answer (score 0):

In the News web part settings, you set "**Number of news posts to show**".

[image]

The News web part will give priority to displaying your **latest news** based on this number.

You can manually organize the news to be displayed by [Organizing posts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165#bkmk_organize). Under this setting, you can freely set the news you want to display and their display order.

[image]